# save dropdownlist selectedvalue from datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview of questions then a dropdownlist of the possible answers for each question.  I want to save the AnswerID (dropdownlist.selecteditem.value) at the click of the btnSaveQuestions_Click event.  However, after trying, my version of Visual Web Developer 2010 does not give me any errors, but when viewing in Internet Explorer (version 10.0.9200.17377, and yes company policy requires that I have this usable in Internet Explorer) it states that at the line "Dim AnswerID as String = ddAnswer.SelectedValue" is not set to an instance of an object.  Any assistance will be appreciated.

```html
<asp:DataGrid id="dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid" runat="server" cssClass="dgBlue" horizontalalign="center" width="90%" OnItemCreated="dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid_ItemDataBound" CellPadding="3"
AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <HeaderStyle backcolor="#A09CBF" />
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="QuestionID" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="QuestionId" Visible="False"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="QuestionText" HeaderText="Question Text">
      <ItemStyle width="60%" horizontalalign="left" />
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Answers">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropdownList id="ddAnswers" runat="server" DataValueField="AnswerID" DataTextField="AnswerText"></asp:DropdownList>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
  </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

```html
Sub dgFacilityQuestionsDataGrid()
        ' create the SQL query that will populate the grid, then call, then bind
        Dim SQLString1 As String = "SELECT QuestionID, QuestionText FROM Questions"
        dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid.DataSource = Global.ASP.Global.SQLSelect(SQLString1, "Proposal")
        dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid.DataBind()
    End Sub ' End dgFacilityQuestionsDataGrid()
    
    Sub dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid_ItemCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs)
        ' datagrid formatting before data is bound to the datagrid - this does not care what data is put into the datagrid
        Select Case e.Item.ItemType
            Case ListItemType.Item, ListItemType.AlternatingItem, ListItemType.EditItem
                ' add additional attributes based on mouseover and mouse out user actions
                e.Item.Attributes.Add("onMouseOver", "this.style.backgroundColor = '#A09CBF'")
                e.Item.Attributes.Add("onMouseOut", "this.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF'")
                ' add buttons as necessary for control if buttons are within the datagrid
                ' Cells(#) and Controls(0) correspond to what column that button resides in the table starting at zero (0)
                
        End Select
    End Sub ' End dgFacilityQuesitonsDataGrid_ItemCreated()
    
    Sub dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid_ItemDataBound(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridItemEventArgs)
        ' datagrid formatting once data is bound - this depends on what data is actually produced for the datagrid
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or _
        e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            If lblQuestionsDone.Text = "False" Then
                Dim mydropdownlist As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("ddAnswers")
                Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT AnswerID, AnswerText FROM QuestionAnswersLink WHERE QuestionID = " & e.Item.Cells(0).Text
                Global.ASP.Global.refresh_ddProposal(0, SQLString, mydropdownlist)
            Else
                Dim mydropdownlist As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("ddAnswers")
                Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT AnswerID, AnswerText FROM QuestionAnswersLink WHERE QuestionID = " & e.Item.Cells(0).Text
                Global.ASP.Global.refresh_ddProposal(0, SQLString, mydropdownlist)
                ' set the showing value as the one chosen from the database
            End If
            
        End If
    End Sub ' End dgFacilityQuestionsDataGrid_ItemDataBound()
```

```html
Sub btnSaveQuestions_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If btnSaveQuestions.Text = "Save Answers" Then ' questions answered for the first time
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each dr As DataGridItem In dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid.Items
                Dim ddAnswer As DropDownList = CType(dgFacilityQuestions_DataGrid.FindControl("ddAnswers"), DropDownList)
                Dim AnswerID As String = ddAnswer.SelectedValue
                If AnswerID <> 0 Then
                    Global.ASP.Global.SQLInsert("INSERT INTO ProposalFacilityQuestionLink (ProposalFacilityID, AnswerID) VALUES ('" & lblFacilityID.Text & "','" & AnswerID & "')")
                End If
                i = i + 1
            Next
        ElseIf btnSaveQuestions.Text = "Save Changes" Then ' answers changed
            
            
        End If
    End Sub ' End btnSaveQuestions_Click()
```

Comment: Please fix your tags the question isnt clear and misleading...

Comment: I think your `FindControl` didnt find it. Have you set a breakpoint on that line? If you do, press F10 and step through it. Check the variable and make sure it is something...

Comment: Also there are more issue that I can see but has a great answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024892/get-selected-value-from-a-dropdownlist-asp-net already...